# How to find the length of 2 lists and compare them in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I've wrote this code which takes a list and find the length..

```
percent(List,Int):-
   percent1(List,0,Int).

percent1([],New,New).
percent1([H|T],New,An):-
   Sum is New +1,
   percent1(T,Sum,An).
```

And I have this KB

```
kb(iron_defficiency,[headache,dizziness,cold,weakness,fatigue,heartbeat,loss_concentration,swelling_tongue,breath],[gender,pregnancy,vitamin_poor_diet,fe,feritin,b12,hb,hct,mcv,plt,wbc,rtc]).
kb(thalassemia,[loss_appetite,painful_spleen,pale_skin],[gender,parent1,parent2,face_features,fe,feritin,b12,hb,hct,mcv,plt,wbc,hbf,hba1,hba2,rtc]).
kb(minor_thalassemia,[headache,fatigue,weakness,pale_skin,swelling_tongue,cold,heartbeat,loss_concentration,breath,dizziness],[vitamin_poor_diet,gender,pregnancy,parent1,parent2,hbaf,hba2,fe,feritin,b12,hb,hct,mcv,plt,wbc,rtc]).
[loss_appetite,weakness,vitamin_poor_diet,heartbeat,loss_weight,breath,pale_skin,headache,fatigue],[medication,alcohol,fe,feritin,b12,hb,hct,mcv,plt,wbc,folic_acid,b12,rtc]).
```

Now i want to take the first list and see which of those items are in kb, return a list on each kb and then compare the length of those lists and find the percentage value.
Example

> if (Length_list==5 and Length_kb_iron==3) then k=3/5*100.

and do this on all kb and the result i want to be like

> Result= [minor 50%, iron_deficiency 75% ......]

i've already make a predicate that finds the list and return only the diseases but i don't know how to calculate this i asked.

```
findDiseases(PositiveSymptoms, Diseases) :-
   findDiseases(PositiveSymptoms, Diseases, []).

findDiseases([], Answer, Answer).
findDiseases([H|T], Diseases, Answer) :-
   findall(Disease,
         (  kb(Disease,Simptoms_list,Feauture_list),
            ( member(H,Simptoms_list) ; member(H,Feauture_list) )
         ),
        As),
   append(As, Answer, NewAnswer),
   findDiseases(T, Diseases, NewAnswer).
```

Comment: You really should use the built-in `length/2` for the length of lists. I cannot come up with a single good reason not to.

Comment: before append i wrote length(As,N) and to the end i wrote writeln(N). But how can i take those integers and return the result i want?
Can you help me?
The results now are

**3

4

Diseases = [iron_deficiency, minor, drepanocytocis, b12]**

Comment: @DebbieMp it's unclear what your question is. Are you asking how to perform an arithmetic operation in Prolog? If you have `X` and `Y`, you can compute, `Result is (X * 100)/Y` to get the percentage ration of `X` to `Y`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to calculate the percentages of positive symptoms that match symptoms or features of diseases in your knowledge base. As you already have a predicate that describes a list of diseases with matching symptoms/features you can use the predicates intersection/3 and length/2 to find out how many of the positive symptoms actually match.

```
percentages(PositiveSymptoms,DisPerc) :-
    findDiseases(PositiveSymptoms,DList),
    list_set(DList,DSet),
    symptoms_diseases_percentages(PositiveSymptoms,DSet,DisPerc).

symptoms_diseases_percentages(_S,[],[]).
symptoms_diseases_percentages(S,[D|Ds],[D-P|DPs]) :-
    kb(D,Slist,Flist),
    intersection(S,Slist,I1),
    intersection(S,Flist,I2),
    length(S,LenS),
    length(I1,LenI1),
    length(I2,LenI2),
    P is ((LenI1+LenI2) / LenS) * 100,
    symptoms_diseases_percentages(S,Ds,DPs).

% list_set(List1,List2)
% List2 ist List1 without duplicates
list_set([],[]).
list_set([X|Xs],[X|Ys]) :-
    subtract(Xs,[X],Zs),
    list_set(Zs,Ys).
```

The predicate percentages/2 is describing a list of matching diseases and percentages for a given list of positive symptoms. For example in the query below `thalassemia-25.0` means 25% of the 4 given symptoms match symptoms/features of the disease thalassemia.

```
?- percentages([headache,cold,heartbeat,pale_skin],D).
D = [thalassemia-25.0,minor_thalassemia-100.0,iron_defficiency-75.0]
```

Note that this approach only works if the lists for symptoms and features of a disease are disjoint. Otherwise you might get percentages above 100%.

Comment: Ok, but why not use `sort/2` instead of `list_set/2` -- and `subtract/3` ?

Comment: @repeat: Frankly, it didn't occur to me. I still tend to think about sort/2 as a predicate that describes a specific reordering of a given list, with the removal of duplicates being only a side effect. From this perspective I still find list_set/2 more intuitive to read. But you are right, from an efficiency perspective sort/2 would be preferable. And list_set/2 could be defined as a single rule with the single goal sort/2.

Comment: Both `sets:subtract/3` in SICStus and `lists:subtract/3` in SWI are non-monotonic. So is `sort/2`, but at least it is portable and fast:)

Comment: To use `sort/2` safely do it like so: `list_set(Es,Xs) :- ( ground(Es) -> sort(Es,Xs) ; throw(error(instantiation_error,_)) ).`

Comment: @repeat: I assume the same is the case for lists:subtract/3 in YAP, yes? Thanks for the hint with ground/1.

Comment: I just checked that with yap 6.2.2: `?- E=2, subtract([1,2,3],[E],Xs), E=2.` succeeds, but `?- subtract([1,2,3],[E],Xs), E=2.` fails.

Comment: Using built-ins like `sort/2` or `keysort/2` is alright, but testing for sufficient instantiation is important! Or else GIGO ensues.